# Why is this file not cached in the browser? What's wrong with my headers?

Tags: caching, http-headers, amazon-cloudfront

I'm using Cloudfront (with Cloudflare in front) to serve the following file:

https://app.astrobin.com/assets/i18n/en.po?version=1623337803841

These are the response header at the time of writing:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
age: 2825
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-ray: 65d3e1df6fe70f9a-VIE
cf-request-id: 0a984b7fa400000f9ac0139000000001
content-length: 6626
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 16:12:37 GMT
etag: "6336cef3a9da96c3c432813762cd7d70"
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
last-modified: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 15:17:27 GMT
nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v2?s=TipuJtVNh6YvmqS4rzXv5mtQ%2BUKVHBvok88InKPm%2FNGqK13b2EX1%2BxMEuMfCgp4qslhW0xc1qeIzX1xpUzNW5u5rC8Di3lsb4zNqaoN0zhhH5E3wbizW%2FjlbqD5C"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
via: 1.1 3d4555926457517be3e728d2175d92a3.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: MfDo647EBTxmyo7TZ-sseALca4bmzBPdPPnuiesvGjNnlkgqLzgwDA==
x-amz-cf-pop: VIE50-C2
x-cache: Hit from cloudfront
```

The following image is my Cloudfront "behavior" rule for that file:

[image: Cloudfront Behavior]

I don't have any Page Rules in Cloudflare for this file.

I'm performing multiple requests to this file, for testing purposes, but the file is never fetched from Chrome's disk or memory cache. It always goes to the network.

[image: Requests]

As you can see from the request URL, I append the timestamp of the last known modification to this file, for cache-busting purposes, so I would like the file to be cached in the browser.

What am I missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser caching is determined by the caching headers (namely `Cache-Control` or `Expires`) in the response from the origin server. But the response you listed doesn't have such a header, so it's up to the browser to determine how long the resource is considered fresh.

If you want the browser to use a particular cache policy you should add a `Cache-Control` header to the response.

Comment: Thanks, but what about `last-modified`? I'm including that header on the assumption that the browser will check it's latest retrieval time against `last-modified` and decide whether to fetch again or show a cached page.

Comment: @SalvatoreIovene: No, that is not how caching works. The response uses `Cache-Control` to tell the client how long it can serve the page without checking back with the server. Once that time has passed, the client will make a [conditional request](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232) (using the `Last-Modified` and `ETag` values) to see if its version is still current. That part is working fine, which is why you're seeing a small `304` instead of a large `200`. The problem is that you haven't told the browser how long it should serve the file from the browser cache.